# Get the correct last ID from table

Tags: sql, pdo

How can I make a SQL query in PDO know what the next ID is? I have tested `$sql->lastInsertId()` and `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() FROM my_table` but according to those the last ID is 116 when the last ID is 66 in my table.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

would `select max(lastID) from my_table` work? (Assuming the column name containing the ID last created is called lastID)

Comment: That did it! :) Many thanks! I'll accept your answer as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1):

`LAST_INSERT_ID()` returns the last ID that was inserted with the autoincrementation. Actually since then records could be deleted (maybe all of them from 67-116), but this does not change the autoincrement position, and the next id will be 117.

If you wnat to know what is the biggest id in your table, then `SELECT max(id) FROM table` can help you.

Comment: Ah! So it's because of that it returned 116

Comment: Actually it is all in the manual :) http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Answer (score 1):

I hope to persuade you to change your mind:

- One **should not** wish to know the next id
- there is **no way** to know what would be next.

An id is just an abstract value, resembling the number just by accident. It's purpose is to be **unique**. This means **no values have to be reused ever**. So, it will always have to be a brand new id.

That's why your database makes it 116, not 66.
That's why you have to be content with 116, not forcing it to be 66

Not to mention that both `lastInsertId()` and `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` are guaranteed to be the right value, while accepted the accepted answer which suggests using `max(lastID)` is not.

Answer (score 0):

If you have auto-increment on ID column, the next ID is not always `last item's ID + 1`. So if you insert two elements (IDs 1 and 2), delete the second one and insert new one again, its ID will be 3, not 2, but it also depends of your DB engine.

But if you want to get last item's ID you may, for example, order the column by descending ID and select the first item's ID